# Drag and Drop - How to get the actual html in dragstart event and drop event

Tags: javascript, angular, html, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

On `dragstart` event I want to get the actual html of dragged element. 
But when I do something like this in a `dragstart`  event 
`console.log( e.target);` it give me the output  like this as expected;

```
<p style="margin-right:72.45pt; margin-left:50.15pt; text-align:center; font-size:16pt" draggable="true"><strong>CONSULTING AND TECHNICAL SERVICES + (CATS+)</strong></p>
```

but this code   `console.log(JSON.stringify(e.target));` give me output like this ;

```
{"__zone_symbol__dragstartfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"running","source":"HTMLParagraphElement.addEventListener:dragstart","zone":"angular","runCount":2}]}
```

when send data from `dragstart` to `drop` event like this

```
 e.dataTransfer.setData('Id', e.target);
```

and then catch data from `e.dataTransfer` in drop event

```
 let sourceElement = event.dataTransfer.getData("Id");
    console.log((sourceElement).innerHTML);
    console.log((sourceElement).outerHTML);
```

I end up with this output `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`
Now , how I convert this `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` into a presentable HTML on UI as I tried `.innerHTML and .outerHTML` but it gives me *undefined* on screen rather proper output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dragestart` event use this

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.currentTarget.outerHTML);
```

Instead of

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('Id', e.target);
```

While in drop event you will get the HTML string. 
Convert that string into an HTML element as follow

```
  let sourceElement = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    let doc: any = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sourceElement, "text/html");
    var clonedSourceHtmlElement: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>(<HTMLElement>doc.firstChild.children[1].children[0]).cloneNode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the bottom approach to do this type of things.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad ;
but the problem is that I don't  have the id attribute in my html which comes from a service , that's why I am searching the other way to get it without ID.